# crictl with containerd permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, containerd, crictl

I installed the latest kubernetes on my cluster, along with `containerd` and `crictl`. however, when it seems that I need to use `sudo` to work with `containerd` EG: `sudo containerd ps`. Without `sudo`, I get a `permission denied` errors.

based on kubernetes instruction, I need to add this:

```
sudo vim /etc/crictl.yaml

runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
image-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
timeout: 10
debug: true
```

So when I use crictl it'll point to `containerd`. however, when I perform `crictl pods` it gives me a permission denied error. Is it possible to work with crictl / containerd without sudo?

Can't seem to find much information online, a lot of it is related to docker.